# React Native ListView with fixed section header that can be updated

Tags: ios, listview, react-native

I made a section header in my listview that responds to state changes but I realised I need it to be fixed. But upon changing it from renderHeader to renderSectionHeader it is fixed but then no longer responds to state changes.

```
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
      renderRow={this._renderRow}
    />

renderHeader: function() {
return (
  <View>
    <Text>{this.state.header}</Text>
  </View>
```

In this way if the state is changed, the text (or whatever it is) will update accordingly. But when scrolling the list the header is not fixed.

```
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
      renderRow={this._renderRow}
    />

renderSectionHeader: function() {
return (
  <View>
    <Text>{this.state.header}</Text>
  </View>
```

With the code as above however, the section header is fixed in place when scrolling but when making alterations to state they strangely do not update in the section header as they do with the ordinary header.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `renderSectionHeader` to render your header, you need to use `cloneWithRowsAndSections` as opposed to `cloneWithRows`.

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1706) is a pretty good discussion on how to implement this depending on your data.

[Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/72d3d724a3a0c6bc46981efd0dad8f7f61121a47/Libraries/CustomComponents/ListView/ListViewDataSource.js#L163) is the implementation of `cloneWithRowsAndSections` on GitHub.

Comment: It doesn't work if you set it up with cloneWithRowsAndSections either. No matter what, the section header doesn't respond to state changes but the header does....